# facebook information for user revived after it is authenticated in session control

Tags: facebook-graph-api, omniauth, parse-platform

I am working with omniauth to sign in the user through facebook(facebook login).
That happens in session controller. My backend database in handled by parse.com, basically it provides an authdata field which just stores

```
"id": "user's Facebook id number as a string",
    "access_token": "an authorized Facebook access token for the user",
    "expiration_date": "token expiration date of the format: yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
```

Once all this information is stored, the user is directed to his profile, I would like to show the user's facebook display picture, I am not so sure how do I do that.
My session_controller looks like this

```
def createfb

    auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    user = User.authenticate_with_facebook(auth.uid, auth.credentials.token, Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at))

    #check if username and name is nil
   if user
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      if (session[:return_to] && user.name == nil)  
        redirect_to "/users/#{current_user.id}/edit"
      elsif (user.name == nil)
         redirect_to "/users/#{current_user.id}/edit"
      else
        redirect_to games_url, :notice =>  "Logged in"
      end
  end
end
```

I would really appreciate if someone can help me out here.
Thank You

PS: I just start ruby on rails a month ago, so I am still a very newbie =)

Comment: You can also email feedback@parse.com for any questions specific to Parse's platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the user’s profile picture by just embeding an IMG element with it’s src set to

```
http(s)://graph.facebook.com/userid/picture
```

For more info on additional options see docs, section “Connections” -> picture.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/